# What is the smallest point set that shatters a set of five points up to isometry?

Tags: geometry

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $C$ be the set of all images of $A$ under isometries of the plane (translations, rotations, and reflections, but no scaling). We say that $C$ [*shatters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shattered_set) $B$ (or that $A$ shatters $B$ up to isometry) if

$$\forall S\subseteq B\ \ \exists c\in C: c\cap B=S$$

For a given integer $n\ge 1$, what is the smallest point set $A$ that can shatter a set of $n$ points up to isometry?

Obviously we must have $|A|\ge |B|$, considering the case $S=B$. If $n=1,2,3,$ taking $A=B$ works for almost any $B$ (the only failure is if $B$ consists of three equally spaced points on a line). $A=B$ is also possible if $B$ consists of four vertices of a regular pentagon.

However, if $|B|=5$, I believe I have a proof that $A=B$ is impossible, so we have at least $|A|\ge 6$. Can we achieve an $A$ of size $6$?

The best solution I have found is $|A|=7$; the set of five black points below on the square grid can be shattered by the union of the black and red points.

[image]

Can this be improved upon? Is this question investigated anywhere in the literature?